# computeRatio() method not working in newly created class

Tags: class

Beginner Java problem. I have an assignment that requires me to create a new class and in that class is a computeRatio() method that divides variables LDL by HDL and prints out the ratio. I can't seem to get the calculation to work and print out. I'll post the code I have an the output I get. I appreciate any guidance you can give.

'public class SimonChristopher_Checkup {

```
private int patient;
private int systolic;
private int diastolic;
private int ldl;
private int hdl;

public static void computeRatio(int ldl, int hdl) { // Divides LDL by HDL
    // to return ratio
    double ratio = ldl/hdl;
    System.out.println("The ratio of good and bad cholesterol is " + ratio + ".");
}

public SimonChristopher_Checkup(int p, int s, int d, int l, int h) { // constructor
    patient = p;
    systolic = s;
    diastolic = d;
    ldl = l;
    hdl = h;
}

public int getPatient() { // accessor (getters)
    return patient;
}

public void setPatient(int p) { // mutator (setter)
    if (p > 0 && p <= 100) {
        patient = p;
    }
}

public int getSystolic() { // accessor (getters)
    return systolic;
}

public void setSystolic(int s) { // mutator (setter)
    if (s >= 100 && s <= 150) {
        systolic = s;
    }
}

public int getDiastolic() { // accessor (getters)
    return diastolic;
}

public void setDiastolic(int d) { // mutator (setter)
    if (d >= 50 && d <= 120) {
        diastolic = d;
    }
}

public int getLdl() { // accessor (getters)
    return ldl;
}

public void setLdl(int l) { // mutator (setter)
    {
        ldl = l;
    }
}

public int getHdl() { // accessor (getters)
    return hdl;
}

public void setHdl(int h) { // mutator (setter)
    {
        hdl = h;
    }
}

public String toString() { // mandatory convention: returns a String object
                            // representation
    String result;
    result = "Patient number: " + patient + "\n" + "Systolic: " + systolic + "\n" + "Diastolic: " + diastolic + "\n"
            + "LDL: " + ldl + "\n" + "HDL: " + hdl + "\n"
            + "HDL is known as good chloresterol. A ratio of 3.5 or better is considered optimal.";
    return result;

}
```

}
`
public class Simon_TestCheckup {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SimonChristopher_Checkup patient1 = new SimonChristopher_Checkup(223, 100, 80, 105, 60);
    SimonChristopher_Checkup patient2 = new SimonChristopher_Checkup(244, 102, 76, 101, 62);



    System.out.println(patient1);
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(patient2);
}
```

}
    When I run TestCheckup I get the following output:

Patient number: 223
Systolic: 100
Diastolic: 80
LDL: 105
HDL: 60

### HDL is known as good chloresterol. A ratio of 3.5 or better is considered optimal.

Patient number: 244
Systolic: 102
Diastolic: 76
LDL: 101
HDL: 62
HDL is known as good chloresterol. A ratio of 3.5 or better is considered optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Few things,

Firstly, it doesn't look like you call upon computeRatio() at any time thus it will never print anything.

Secondly, I would change it to

```
public double computeRatio(int ldl, int hdl) { // Divides LDL by HDL
return ldl/hdl;
}
```

and in your toString() method add:

```
public String toString() { // mandatory convention: returns a String object
                        // representation
String result;
result = "Patient number: " + patient + "\n" + "Systolic: " + systolic + "\n" + "Diastolic: " + diastolic + "\n"
        + "LDL: " + ldl + "\n" + "HDL: " + hdl + "\n"
        + "The ratio of good and bad cholesterol is " + computeRatio(ldl,hdl) + ".");
        + "HDL is known as good chloresterol. A ratio of 3.5 or better is considered optimal.";
return result;
}
```

Also, you may want to declare hdl and ldl as doubles down the line. When you get ratio you're looking to get a double but you're dividing 2 ints. It should work as intended for now but in the future you may run into problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I am struggling through this and appreciate the knowledge you guys share.